# Configuring the Popup Calendar Widget

Tags: 7, views, datetime

Currently I have a date contextual filter. When I click the date field the popup calendar displays. when I click on a date (for example today's date) it displays as `3/18/2014`, but I would like it to display as `March 18th, 2014`. Would anyone know how I should go about this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it seems that the issue would be fixed by reformatting the `Short` date type located in `admin/config/regional/date-time`. Although, I tried this and it was not working.

Then I remembered that I had altered some javascript to add a calendar image button on my form. That javascript was overriding some of the default configurations of the code and after fixing that it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your content type and edit the field. You'll find "More settings and values" as a collapsed fieldset (which is how I always missed it at first.)

The first option will be to change the "Date entry options" and how this is displayed.

[image]

You can also modify the default start and end dates here, as well.

Comment: I believe that this is for setting the actual date (when creating a piece of content). I am talking about on the view side when I am searching by a date and click on that calendar widget. Any ideas for that?

Comment: In my experience setting it there made it take effect when using the exposed Views filter.